# An or A with file names

Tags: american-english

would you say

`anything you install with a .application file`
or

`anything you install with an .application file`

I feel like the "an .application" is right reading it, but "a .application" feels right aloud, because I read it "a dot-application"

Comment: It depends entirely on **how *you* pronounce** ".application". If you **say** "dot-application", then use _a_. If you **say** "application", then use _an_. The rule applies ***ONLY*** to pronunciation, not spelling, not letters, not punctuation, not writing, not your eyes. Only your ears and your mouth. Say it out loud, even if you're writing it; your readers will.

Comment: @John Lawler -  Agreed. For example, some people sound the "h" in "hotel" and others don't. The former would write "a hotel" and the latter, "an hotel."

Comment: @chasly We've been here before. Some aspirate _hotel_ and still use _an_.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth - I suggest that is overcorrection. Someone sees "an hotel" in written form and makes the erroneous assumption that the author would have aspirated the "h"

Comment: @chaslyfromUK It's not an overcorrection. It's how it used to be pronounced. It's changed over time, with fewer people pronouncing it that way now.

Comment: I think you've missed my point. People used to omit the pronunciation of the "h" because "hotel" is adopted from French. Thus it was 'correct' to use "an". When some people began to aspirate it, it made sense to use "a". However some such speakers over-corrected by retaining "an" even though it was no longer appropriate.